# How can I cast a tensor to the complex type in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to do some quantum mechanics calculations with Pytorch, where the quantities are sometimes complex. I would like to know how can I cast an existing real tensor to the complex type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PyTorch does have [complex number support](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/cd4c32691d45c86b030e97f99d03fe4f693918e1).

Try this:

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0], dtype=torch.double)
b = a.type(torch.complex64)
```

Comment: Try that, and get the message: "RuntimeError: Complex dtype not supported." That's in Pytorch 1.5. Maybe it's implemented in nightly?

Comment: @larspars what is your code? The print isn't ready yet in 1.5.0, I think. For now you should avoid printing the variable directly.

Comment: Exact copy paste of your code. Digging through the pytorch issues, it seems constructing complex tensors was supported before, but they removed it since very few operations were supported. They're working on it though.

Comment: @larspars Hmm, this worked with PyTorch 1.4, so perhaps they've had a regression. But the latest nightly can run the code above (plus printing the tensors) with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK pytorch does not support complex tensors.
You can represent a complex tensor using two real ones. However, you will have to implement all the relevant basic arithmetic operations to support these complex tensors.

**However**, there is a serious [commitment](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/755) to add this important feature to pytorch, and it seems like a very active issue.

Comment: That is too sad

Comment: @VladimirVargas it is sad, but you should be [optimistic](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/755).

Comment: Hi, is still true for the current version (V1.7)? Because I notice that a function `torch.angle` is introduced which deals with complex values..